# Reformatting Excel spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, excel

[image]

Hi everyone, I received data in a excel (xls) spreadsheet that is formatted in the first table, illustrated above.

I am attempting to rearrange this data into the format, in the table, just below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much.

Comment: it's on topic. I'm asking for help on how to reformat the data using python.

Comment: @Cilyan wants you to follow [the question asking guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), to which he should have really posted a link in his comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, save it to a `.csv` file

```
import csv

curr = []
with open('file.csv') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    for area, pop10, pop20, pop50 in csv.reader(infile):
        if curr and curr[0] != area:
            outfile.writerow(curr)
            curr = [area, pop10, pop20, pop50]
            continue

        if pop10: curr[1] = pop10
        if pop20: curr[2] = pop20
        if pop50: curr[3] = pop50
```

Comment: starting to make sense. are area,pop10,pop20,pop50 tuples being returned from the reader object? or are these being substituted for the field names?

Comment: @COCO: it seems that you are asking me about [tuple assignment](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment)

Comment: Inspector - this works in csv. thanks. is there any way to perform the reformat in .xls, using xlwt?

Comment: @COCO: there's probably a way to do this with `xlwt`, but I'm not very well versed with that. Sorry, but this the best I can come up with right now

Comment: inspector, so if im understanding correctly the tuples here are the column names..so technically if I had a spreadsheet with more columns..i could do something like for a,b,c,d,e,f,g in csv.reader(file) ?

Comment: @COCO: that is correct. It's kinda like saying `a,b,c = (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty succinctly using Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_excel("in.xlsx")
merged = dataframe.groupby("AREA").sum()
merged.to_excel("out.xlsx")
```

Comment: apparently pandas is not in my out of the box installation and i need admin permission to escalate the matter and get it installed. boo.

Answer (score 0):

so, if the csv has 11 columns where 'AREA' is the second column, would the code be:

```
def CompressRow(in_csv,out_file):
    curr = []
    with open(in_csv) as infile, open(out_file, 'w') as fout:
        outfile = csv.writer(fout)
        for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k in csv.reader(infile):
            if curr and curr[1] != b:
                outfile.writerow(curr)
                curr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
                continue

            if a: curr[0] = a
            if c: curr[2] = c
            if d: curr[3] = d
            if e: curr[4] = e
            if f: curr[5] =f
            if g: curr[6]=g
            if h: curr[7]=h
            if i: curr[8]=i
            if j: curr[9]=j
            if k: curr[10]=k

#execute CompressRow(in_csv,out_file)

I tried executing it and it gives me

if a: curr[0]=a

 IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```